# Hugo/Docsy: execute of template failed at <.url>: can’t evaluate field url in type bool

Tags: html, hugo, hugo-shortcode, docsy

I am developing a static web application using `Hugo` with `Docsy` theme. I would like to add an condition within `Docsy Partials` code where I would like to append the `mailTo:` word to my `.url` if the `.mail` is set to true, when I try to do this then I get the following error:

```
/themes/docsy/layouts/partials/footer.html:36:34": execute of template failed at <.url>: can’t evaluate field url in type bool
```

Following is the code I am adding to my `partials`:

```
{{ $myUrl := "" }}
{{ with .mail }}
 {{ $myUrl = print "mailTo:" .url }}
{{ else }}
 {{ $myUrl = .url }}
{{ end }}
    
{{ $myUrl }}
```

If I add some test then everything would work perfectly:

```
{{ with .mail }}
 TRUE
{{ else }}
 FALSE
{{ end }}
```

I am quite new to the Hugo and Docsy theme so finding difficult to understand and fix it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `with` correct here: https://gohugo.io/functions/with/. I think you should use `if` here.